# css - float header and footer above content, auto resize background with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to reproduce a layout similar to [bulgari.com](http://en.bulgari.com/department.jsp?cat=cat00002) as far as the header, footer and auto resizing the background image goes (i know bulgari.com has a flass movie as a background but I need to use an image that auto resizes to the content div).
I'm not very good a decoding css and jquery so if anyone could spare a few minutes, I'd like to know how I can float the header and footer above the content div and also resize the content background image on document load and window resize events.

I've done this so far but it's pretty basic.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divheight = $(document).height() - $(".header").height() - $(".footer").height();
    $(".main-container").height(divheight);
});

// for the window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    var divheight = $(document).height() - $(".header").height() - $(".footer").height();
    $(".main-container").height(divheight);
});

//-->
</script>
</head>

<body class="bg">
<div class="header"></div> <!-- header end -->

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="content">abc</div>
</div> <!-- main-container end -->

<div class="footer"></div> <!-- footer end -->

<div class="bg-container"></div> <!-- bg-container end -->
</body>
</html>
```

layout.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.bg {
    background: url(../images/thematic.jpg) repeat scroll;
}
.header {
    background: transparent url("../images/trans.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 80px;
    min-width: 990px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.bg-container {
    background: #F00;
}

.footer {
  background: url("../images/trans.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 990px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #999;
}
.main-container {
    min-height: 500px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/7jd7t/
all i did was set the background of the body to fixed, and set the background-size to 100%. No scripting required.

Feel free to let me know if this is not what you are after...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the content div to appear under the header div and begin from the top of the browser window. Also, when resizing the window, the footer must always be at the bottom of the viewport, until the min-height of content is met.

Answer (score 0):

Copying another site, can't help you with that.
but as far as floating header and footers go,
If what you want is that they stick to the top and bottom and appear above other content, this can be easily accomplished using pure css.

HTML:

```
<header id="fixedhead">
Your header content goes here
</header>

<footer id="fixedfoot">
Footer content
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
#fixedhead{
position: absolute;
z-index:1000;
top: 0;
bacground-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) /*50% transparent black background*/
}
#fixedfoot{
position: absolute;
z-index:1000;
bottom: 0;
bacground-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) /*50% transparent black background*/
}
```